# How do I find the largest index in a list

Tags: c

how do i print the highest index number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The highest index is just one less than the length of the list. So:

```
puts [expr {[llength $list] - 1}]
```

To print the element at the largest index, you can refer to it as 'end':

```
puts [lindex $list end]
```

If I misunderstood the question and you want the index of the largest number in the list, that can be done as follows:

```
puts [lindex [lsort -indices -integer -decreasing $list] 0]
```

Comment: What if the list had empty indexes?

Comment: Tcl doesn't have sparse lists, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: If a list has 1,_,3,4,_,7...etc the index would be diffewrent from the length, or can you not do that? Thanks

Comment: What makes you think that the index would be different from the length? At index 0, there's 1, at index 1 there's an empty string, at index 2 there's 3, etc. Unless your actual question is to find the largest index of elements in that list after ignoring/removing empty elements? For which the simplest solution would possibly be to first remove those empty elements then proceed as above.

Comment: No. As I said, Tcl doesn't have sparse lists. The best you can do is to have empty strings as the skipped indexes, but they are counted towards the length of the list, so the last index is still length - 1.

Comment: Tcl uses a fairly efficient representation of lists internally, but they're not sparse; there is a classic C array underneath. For sparse datastructures, see a dictionary (of values) or associative array (of variables).